# Could a Nautilus Shell, Squid Gladius, or similar structure eventually form the basis of a Spinal column/Skeletal system?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution, aliens

Ok, so, some quick background... I'm not an evolutionary biologist or anything, but I'm helping a friend with some alien design ideas, and at least one of them she designed and wanted help to somehow explain was a group that basically falls into the classic Star Trek "Humans but Kinda Weird-Looking" milieu... and while I was initially willing to handwave their existence with "Boy, space sure is wacky, what are the odds that it keeps making humans!", I kept thinking about it more and more, and I actually really *liked* the idea of something we might consider a "functional vertebrate" with seemingly mammalian- even HUMANOID- characteristics actually being a case of something we would possibly classify as an Invertebrate undergoing some Seriously Bizarre Convergent Evolution that took a completely different path from ours... Yet ended up with a Weirdly Similar Result?

So we ended up coming up with a pretty solid model for how this race evolved, why they have the adaptations that they do, and we have them pretty solidly fleshed out... Except that there's one thing that I'm not 100% sure about, and it's kind of a Big Freaking Deal if we want an alternatively-evolved "Vertebrate": given that the ancestor we envisioned for them was something akin to what might have happened if Cephalopods or other Molluscan Critters had somehow developed into Primitive Chordates, the way something like the Lancet did, How Would They Evolve A Skeletal Structure, and How different would it be from Ours?

So I looked back at something like an Ammonite, and wondered if it was possible for something that still had a vestigial mollusk-style shell after somehow developing an early [Notocord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notochord) to sort of... Use that as a springboard for developing Vertebrae to protect it, and the rest of the skeleton following suit? Could the "chambers" in the shell maybe... start to diverge into separate nested "bands to allow for freedom of movement, or something like that?

Comment: You are looking at organisms which are way too evolved, too specialized. For an idea of where vertebrates come form, look at the [amphioxus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancelet). Fun factoid: among the inverterbrates, our closest relatives are the [echinoderms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinoderm) (starfish, sea urchins, sea cucumbers, [crinoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crinoid) and their allies). [Tunicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunicate) ([salps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaliacea), sea squirts) are some weird [chordates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordate).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about too... Though I guess since it's an alien world the Proto-Thing would just have to be LIKE something instead of being "The Thing But ____" XD

Comment: Though I guess the question I'm trying to ask is less "Can this Happen" and more like "Ok, assume These Things have *Already* Happened, and that somehow we now Have An Organism that has both a Cuttlebone/Gladius-Style Thing *and* a Notocord-ish Thing, what are some ways in which the One might start to develop into shielding for the Other?" Sorry for the confusion, I guess I didn't state that very clearly :( The Amphioxus thing is pretty helpful though, THEIR spines had to come from Somewhere, right? Maybe they'll give me some ideas, thanks! :D

Comment: The vertebral column does not *sheath* the notochord, it *replaces* it. The notochord does not need sheathing, it is a structural construction element. You are thinking of the [neural tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_tube), which is a separate structure.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that's actually really helpful! I only just started looking into how Spines actually work/where they come from and I might be in a little over my head here XD So the thing I'm looking to protect is the *Neural Tube*, not the Notocord... Ok, that might make researching a little easier, thanks! :D

Comment: Are you just looking for something that looks like a spine or do you want it to have the function of the spine as a major component in the nervous system as well?

Comment: Huh, Good question... At the very least I feel like it should be able to support a bipedal body plan/hold the rest of a skeleton together in a similar way as a spine, I guess it doesn't necessarily HAVE to mean their nervous system is the same as ours? I guess what my friend is shooting for is "looks and moves like a Human does", and I suppose I just assumed having similar nerves in the spine had something to do with how we bend and move? But if that's not necessarily the case, then an alternate nervous system and the spine/skeleton just acting as an Armature could also be really interesting!

Comment: That does beg another question though... Why would they develop a spine in the first place otherwise? It seems like the first spines happened because they protected the nervous system, and the structural support was kind of an added bonus that other developments grew out from? I guess they'd need another reason to develop Rigidity... Or their spines DO work like ours...? I might be grasping at straws here, but which do you guys think would work better?

Answer (score 6):

Basal chordates lack a jointed vertebral column, and have instead a rigid cartilaginous "notochord".

A gladius is very similar to a notochord. If chordates could 
do it, so can cephalopods.

However, I doubt that squids would become terrestrial. They're pelagic specialists. Most people use octopuses or cuttlefish for their terrestrial cephalopod ancestors.

Comment: Yeah, we were actually thinking Cuttlefish, since her people often Radically Alter Their Skintone as a form of communication and expression :D

Comment: The entire point of the notochord is that it is *not* rigid. It is flexible and elastic. Its role is to store energy in the same way as the elastic limbs of a bow.

Comment: @AlexP Fair enough. I'll change it to "unbroken".

Comment: Cool! So they could probably develop a Spine-Like thing? I'm assuming it might look a little different than ours, and would probably be made of something like Chitin and/or something like Aragonite, like a Cuttlebone... I'll look and see if anyone's asked about how that would affect them, maybe make a new question if no one has. :3

Comment: @BonnetBee I think gladii are made of calcium carbonate. This paper explains why vertebrates use calcium phosphate in their skeletons rather than other, more common materials: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28563613/ It's not exactly in layman's terms, but you could probably figure out the consequences of a non-calcium phosphate skeleton from the abstract.

Comment: Thanks! I guess whatever they end up being made of might also tell us something about the planet they live on?

Comment: @SealBoi I guess an animal that either never goes into anaerobic respiration or produces different byproducts (like alcohol) wouldn't have that problem? Although an animal like that would probably be too different from a standard vertebrate to fit the op's requirements.

Comment: @BonnetBee Well, yeah, kind of, but nothing too different from Earth, anyway. Snails, chitons, limpets, clams, corals, urchins, and a bunch of other critters use calcium carbonate in their shells too.

Comment: @Bellerophon Yeah, I guess so. In any case, it's not like people will be calling BonnetBee out on it, it's pretty obscure biology.

Answer (score 3):

how about this. Similar to how "whales had to wait until their noses migrated to the top of their heads" (quoting the book 'Sapiens' by Harari) in order to facilitate breathing while swimming, in your case it was the exoskeleton that migrated to the interior of the body, in order to more closely focus their protection on the nervous system. I can envision the soft tissues gradually "seeping through" to the outside of the exoskeleton in response to a shrinking exoskeleton, perhaps due to a shortage of calcium in the environment.

Comment: Hmmmm! That certainly helps add to the theme of "Looks like a familiar thing but evolved RADICALLY differently", I like it!